# Re-inflating the same menu across all activities in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I would like some advice on how to properly inflate a toolbar in your activities, so that any input from any activity uses the same menu defined in a menu.xml resource.

Code below has the following:

1. Classes `MainActivity` and `Screen0`
2. layouts for `MainActivity` and `Screen0`
3. the menu.xml

As it stands, menu inflation on the first activity happens, works fine. When it gets to the next screen (`Screen0`), I define the toolbar again in`Screen0`'s layout, but with `android:id="@id/my_toolbar_initial_screen"` instead of `android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_initial_screen"` like in the `MainActivity`layout.

My issue is that when I press the mute button on `Screen0`'s layout, it starts another instance of audio in `Screen0`. I need both toolbars on both screens to be linked together so if the user presses mute on `Screen0`'s layout, it understands its interacting with the same menu from `MainActivity`'s layout.

What's the correct way to do this?

Manifest:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.finalProject">
    <activity android:name=".Screen0"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.finalProject">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer gMusic;
MediaPlayer gMusicBattleSong;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load initial screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set a tool bar using androidx library (more updated version of zybooks example)
    Toolbar myToolBar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar_initial_screen);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolBar);

    // gMusic is a global MediaPlayer type
    gMusic = new MediaPlayer();

    // loading an mp3 into the gMusic object
    gMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.battle_theme);

}
```

Screen0.java

```
public class Screen0 extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.screen0);

    Toolbar myToolBar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar_initial_screen);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolBar);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}
```

activty_main.xml layout

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:actionBarNavMode="standard"
    >
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_initial_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/Sapphire"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

    />
```

Screen0.xml layout

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Screen0">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@id/my_toolbar_initial_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/Sapphire"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



<!-- Mute the music  -->
<item android:id="@+id/mute_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/mute_music"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="muteMusic"
    />


<!-- Restart menu item -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/restart_menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/light_bulb"
    android:title="@string/restart"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:onClick="restartStory"
    />
```

Comment: Please post actual code of what you're trying and explain what you expect and what is not working. A description of a general problem is insufficient and vague. Consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now though, when the mute button gets pressed on the next layout screen, it plays another instance of the audio over top of the audio already playing.

Your problem is not the dupcliate toolbar - your problem is playing multiple streams of audio.

I don't know what the architecture of your app looks like, or how to deal with audio on Android, but generally speaking you should have *one* handle to the current audio stream that you can play / pause / stop / mute / whatever. This could be maintained as a Singleton or Service or whatever. Then each toolbar would interact with the *one and only* controller for the audio stream.

Comment: Righto! The single handle part is what I'm trying to figure out. I could either duplicate the same toolbar across each layout, or use different toolbars pointing to a single handle per menu item. Either way works, I'm just not sure how to go about either way